# Type casting an object to any Collection type

Tags: java, oop, collections

We recently faced a bug in our code which was basically related to OOPs concepts.

```
class ABC
{
    String a;
    ABC(){
        a = "abc";
    }
}

public class Main {


    static Object listABC() {
        List<ABC> listOfABC = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfABC.add(new ABC());
        return listOfABC;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        List<Long> listLong = (List) Main.listABC();
        System.out.println(listLong.get(0));
    }
}
```

> Output: ABC@642c39d2

Shouldn't this raise a run time exception ? Can someone point me to the correct direction as to why doesn't this code raise an exception?

Comment: Your existing list is type of <ABC> and you are casting it to LONG

Comment: Yes, it doesn't raise any run time exception

Comment: @rmagon because generics are gone after compiling. You wont get a `Runtime` exception because the compiler cares for the correct type. If at `Runtime` something is in for a different class defined by the generics there wont be an expcetion because the generic type of the `List` doesn´t exist anymore

Comment: @ScaryWombat no it doesn't, I've edited it now

Comment: But you would get a ClassCastException if you tried to assign `listLong.get(0)` to a Long

Comment: Generics exist only in your IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generic types are erased, and in your example info about them no longer exists at runtime. They're only a compile time aid. Casting List<T> to List also discards info about the type at compile time, although it's still a valid cast.

So as long as you're doing legal casts at every step, which you are, it'll compile fine. At runtime the info about the type in the list is gone here.

If you tried to cast get(0) to a Long *then* youd get a classcastexception, since the item itself is an ABC.

Comment: The actual story is more complex, it is better to say that _in this particular example_, generic types are gone. For example, type parameters on a field or method parameter are available to reflection; if you implement a generic interface with a non-generic class, the type literals you used are also available. In Java, erasure is a mess.

Comment: @Marko Yeah. Well, it's a big can of worms. But I dont know any better way to word it. I'll add an "in this example". But further complaints will have to go to my secretary, lol.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik can you shed some more light please? Maybe point me to some good resources?

Comment: @JasonC I understood what you explained, but now i'm confused with the comments

Comment: In a nutshell: the object which is an instance of a generic type (in your case `ArrayList`) doesn't know about its type parameters, but there are many other situations where generic types occur---on the object's fields, method parameters, etc. Different rules apply for each individual case and the whole picture is anything but pretty.

Comment: @rmagon In a nutshell: It means that, technically, in some cases *information* about type parameters *does* exist at runtime. Its just that that information isn't in the right form or place to be relevant to type casts between A<T>'s and A's. That is, the general statement "information about generic types is gone at runtime" isn't *really* true fsv "information"; it just doesn't apply to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is pretty simple. Generics are compile time components to ensure compile time compatibility. Generics are gone after compiling and hence don´t exist at Runtime anymore.

As `Object listABC` does return a `List`, `(List) Test.listABC();` doesn´t throw an exception, because it´s valid as it actually returns a `List`.

you can assign it to `List<Long> listLong` because at runtime `listLong` doesn´t know about it´s `Long` generic anymore.

As a result this is, even though it looks wrong, valid executable code.

also the only reason this does work is that there is a `PrintStream#println(Object)` method, otherwise you´d get an `Exception` because your trying to call it with a wrong type as you can see in the following example.

```
static Object listABC() {
    List<Test> listOfABC = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfABC.add(new Test());
    return listOfABC;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

    List<Long> listLong = (List) Test.listABC();
    System.out.println(listLong.get(0));
    test(listLong.get(0));
}

private static void test(Long longvalue) {
    System.out.println("TEST");
}
```

O/P

```
ABC@19e0bfd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: ABC cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at ABC.main(ABC.java:19)
```